# How to extract the string between 2 characters in same line on python

Tags: python, string, file

#### Task

I have a text file with alphanumeric filenames:

```
\abc1.txt.  \abc2.txt     \abc3.txt     \abcde3.txt
\Zxcv1.txt        \mnbd2.txt     \dhtdv.txt
```

I need to extract all `.txt` extensions from the file, which will be in the same line and also different line in the file in python.

#### Desired Output:

```
abc1.txt
abc2.txt
abc3.txt
abcde3.txt
Zxcv1.txt
mnbd2.txt
dhtdv.txt
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex).

```
import re

# Open the file with the mode r, which means read the file
with open("text_file.txt", "r") as f:
    # Actually read the content of the file
    file_content = f.read()

# Find everything which matches the given regex code
# This returns a list of the matches
files = re.findall(r"\\(.*?.txt)", file_content)

# Iterate through each item in the list
for file in files:
    # Print the item
    print(file)
```

Here is the explaination of the regex that I used: https://regex101.com/r/DAPlqM/1

Comment: for more exact matching files = re.findall(r"\\(.*?.txt\b)", file_content) will help

Comment: @Justin Remember that you have to escape the backslash. So this is better: `files = re.findall(r"\\(.*?.txt\b)", file_content)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = r"\abc1.txt. \abc2.txt \abc3.txt \abcde3.txt \Zxcv1.txt \mnbd2.txt \dhtdv.txt"
list = string.split("\\")
print(list)
formatted = "\n".join(list)
print(formatted)
```

Results:

```
['', 'abc1.txt. ', 'abc2.txt ', 'abc3.txt ', 'abcde3.txt ', 'Zxcv1.txt ', 'mnbd2.txt ', 'dhtdv.txt']

abc1.txt. 
abc2.txt 
abc3.txt 
abcde3.txt 
Zxcv1.txt 
mnbd2.txt 
dhtdv.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that matches two words delimited by a `.`:

```
import re
print('\n'.join(re.findall(r'\w+\.\w+', s)))
```

Given your input text in variable `s`, this outputs:

```
bc1.txt
bc2.txt
bc3.txt
bcde3.txt
Zxcv1.txt
mnbd2.txt
dhtdv.txt
```